# What kind of food components contain more energy?

Tags: meat, sugar

So what should I build my dishes out from to have an energized, successful day?
**Rephrased:** What do I choose for a dish?

By energy I mean like **carbohydrates** which are in bread, potatoes, sugar and stuff. Energy that allows you to move. I'm not asking how to be stronger or anything.

My understanding of food (extremely simplified):

- bread, potato, sugar `->` energy
- meat `->` protein (build muscle)
- ...

**The question I want to answer for myself:** If I eat meat, can I be sure to ingest enough energy to live through the day?

*(I'm not anything like professional in food stuff and not native English.)*

Comment: There are isn't any starch in sugar, so I edited your question to use a broader term that covers the items you listed.

Comment: Hi Bitterblue! Questions about nutrition - the effect food has on the human body, and the best ways to fulfill our bodies' needs for energy and other nutrients - are very interesting for everybody. But nutrition is a very complex field, full of competing theories not yet proven or disproven by anybody, and there are many things even the specialists don't know. We are not at all specialists in nutrition, just a bunch of people who love to cook. So, when we created the site, we decided that we cannot provide and judge nutrition answers well enough, and made nutrition off topic for us.

Comment: As a consequence, I have to close your question. See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for a description of our site's scope. I know that having your question closed feels very unpleasant, but please don't be discouraged. We know that nobody knows the rules the first time they come to the site, and don't hold it against you. You are still welcome to ask the kind of question we accept, basically focusing on how to cook food, and we'll do our best to answer them. You can also look around on both the help center and the main site to get a better feeling for the way we work.

Comment: @rumtscho Ok, it's not asking "**How** to cook?" I could rephrase the question to ask: "**What** to cook?" ("Ingredient selection") Would it still be off-topic? I don't want to start a discussion, just thinking it's way too much "distinction" here. I would go for a rule of thumb: if it doesn't find a better place on another stack site, it's not off-topic (while asking about corresponding things).

Comment: A rephrasing as "what to cook" is a sure sign that it is not suitable for the site, as it then falls under the "no objective best answer" problem. Your "rule of thumb" is not guaranteed to work: you are welcome to try it when you have an almost-fitting question, and sometimes the site might take it. But each site does have its scope, and if it is off topic, it will be closed. There is no rule that the Stack Exchange network will take any question; on the contrary, one of its main principles is to only accept questions which can be answered well in our format, and refuse the rest.

Comment: @Bitterblue "How" vs "what" isn't really the issue here; you're fundamentally asking about health/nutrition (the effect food has on your body), and that's never been on topic here, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body can derive energy from three main "families" of molecules:

1. Fat. This is the highest density, at about 9 KCalories a gram. There are varying recommendations regarding the amount of fat intake to be healthy, and most major medical establishments have been seriously wrong over the past decades. In my opinion, which works for my body alone, 20% of your calories from fat is about right, but this varies from person to person. Fat is in any oil, fatty fruit (like avocadoes), margarine, animal fats and dairy products. The body can convert fat to glucose for energy as needed.
2. Carbohydrates. This includes sugars, and anything that breaks down into sugars, such as starches and complex carbohydrates. Glucose is a type of sugar that the body needs to burn for energy. Most starches will reduce to glucose via the body's own chemistry. Other simple sugars are metabolized differently, like fructose, which is too long a discussion for here. carbohydrates contain about 4 calories a gram.
3. Proteins. The body needs protein (a set of different amino acids) in order to build muscles, brain and other tissue. However, if needed or if there is an abundance of protein in the diet, the protein can be broken down to carbohydrates and waste products, thus gaining some energy from it, at about 4 calories a gram (like sugar).

From a health perspective, the body is "designed" to take the bulk of its energy from carbohydrates. Taking energy from protein is possible, but a high protein diet has a negative effect on the kidneys over long periods.

As for energy during the day, the release of energy (read glucose) into the bloodstream is governed by the time it takes the body to digest the sugar. The more fibre around the sugar (fruit, vegetables, whole grains etc.) the longer it takes to get to the sugar, and the slower the release. This allows for a relatively constant level of energy.

The opposite would be to eat some pure white sugar (or equivalent in candy or soft drinks). This causes the bloodstream to be flooded with sugar, giving an energy high. Within about 15 minutes, the body's insulin response will kick in and lower the sugar levels, causing a "down".

Comment: When you see a question that's blatantly off topic like this one, it's probably best to not post an answer; we don't want people to get the idea that they can get nutrition answers here as long as someone sneaks one in before the question is closed.